# macro extract data block

Tags: vba, excel

I have worked on this problem for my entire day and can't solve it.

The input data consists of several data blocks with the same number of rows and columns. Each data block has its name in the first line within the block. Besides, they are further separated by a blank row.

```
block1
name score value
 a     2     3
 b     3     5
 c     1     6

block2
name score value
 a     4     6
 b     7     8
 c     2     6

block3
name score value
 a     5     4
 b     7     8
 c     2     9
```

The desired output is to extract the name and value column of each block, and then parallel them in columns. Like this:

```
value  block1  block2 block3
 a       3     6      4
 b       5     8      8
 c       6     6      9
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your answer, Tony, and others!
I just have another requirement. It is possible that some row in some tables are missing. In other words, as you mentioned previously, the row number may vary. Is it possible to fill in the corresponding cell in these tables with NA? i.e. the new input is like:

```
block1
name score value
a     2     3
c     1     6

block2
name score value
a     4     6
b     7     8
c     2     6

block3
name score value
a     5     4
b     7     8
```

The desired output now is like this:

```
value  block1  block2 block3
a       3       6      4
b       NA      8      8
c       6       6      NA
```

**UPDATE on Jul.3 (If it's inappropriate to make the question too long, I will move this part and make it a new question)**

```
 block1
name score value
 a     2     3
 b     3     5
 c     1     6

block2
name score value
 a     4     6
 b     7     8
 c     2     6

block3
name score value
 a     5     4
 b     7     8
 c     2     9
```

How can I pull both the value and its corresponding score and put them into one cell? Like this: The code indicates that the value is put into an dynamic array. Then the .range is assigned to this array. My first thought is to construct another array to store the value of the "score" column. Then loop through each element in both array, and concatenate them together. However, it seems that VBA does allow me to loop through the array, since its dimension is not defined. I tried REDIM, but it did not work.

```
value  block1   block2    block3
 a       3(2)     6(4)      4(5)
 b       5(3)     8(7)      8(7)
 c       6(1)     6(2)      9(2)
```

Comment: are the rows always the same? or do you need some sorting? Is this a one off job or do ypu need a macro that can be run on changing row/column counts?

Comment: I'm confused and made my code really messy. What I'm thinking is to extract the "value" column for all the tables, and rearrange them by dividing this column by the number of rows.

Comment: My answer can be extended reasonably easily.  However, does the sequence of names matter? If the names were in the sequence found in your example, they would be a-c-b.  Do you really want Not applicable in the output; I would leave cell blank for missing values.

Comment: I think the sequence does matter. Why would it be a-c-b? Is it because the first table has row a and c? NA is not required, blanks are fine too.

Comment: If there is one table with every row, the sequence can be deduced from that.  But if no table contains a complete set, it becomes more difficult.  For example, if the tables are a-b, b-c and a-d, it is impossible to tell if the sequence is a-d-b-c, a-b-d-c or a-b-c-d unless they are, for example, in alphabetic sequence.  I have routines that deduce the sequence from partial chains but they would be difficult to convert to VBA.  Are the tables in alphabetic sequence?  Will at least one table contain every row?

Comment: I only have some sample data files instead of the "real" files. But I think only few tables are missing rows. So let's assume that the first table contains every row. Then could you tell me how to tweak your code to do this?

Comment: I am working through my revised code testing it.  It is 21:50 here so I am not sure if I will finish it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First answer - introduction to issues and request for clarification**

This is not a solution - you do not give enough information for a solution - but introduces the issues and possible techniques.  Warning: I have typed this into NotePad; no guarantees that there are no syntax errors.

You say each table is the same size although I assume not 3x3.  But if they were 3x3, could I say table 1 starts in row 1, table 2 starts in row 7 and table N starts in 6(N-1)+1?  That is, can you calculate the position of each table or do you need to search?

If you need to search, the following might help:

```
Dim ColSrcLast as Long
Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long

RowSrcCrnt = 1      ' Assumed start of Table 1

With Worksheets("xxxx")
  ColSrcLast = .Cells(RowCrnt,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

`ColSrcLast = .Cells(RowCrnt,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` is the VBA equivalent of placing the cursor in the last column of row RowCrnt+1 and then clicking Control+Left.  This is probably the easiest way of finding the last used column in table 1.

Control+ArrowKey moves the cursor in the indicated direction and:

- if the current cell is blank, stops at the first non-blank cell,
- if the current cell is non-blank and so is the next, stops at the last non-blank cells before a blank cell,
- if the current cell is non-blank but the next cell is blank, stops at the next non-blank cell,
- if no cell meets the above criteria, stops at the end of range.

Experiment and the above will become clearer.

If the number of blank lines between tables might vary, I think the following will be the easiest method of locating each table:

```
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
Dim RowSrcLast As Long
Dim RowSrcTableTitle As Long
Dim RowSrcTableLast As Long

With Worksheets("xxxx")
  ' Find last used row of worksheet
  RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

RowSrcCrnt = 1

Do While RowSrcCrnt <= RowSrcLast
  With Worksheets("xxxx")
    Found = False
    Do While RowSrcCrnt <= RowSrcLast
      If .Cells(RowSrcCrnt,"A").Value = "" then
        ' Have found start of next (first) table
        RowSrcTableTitle = RowSrcCrnt
        Found = True
        Exit Do
      End If 
      RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcCrnt+1
    Loop
    If Not Found Then
      ' No more tables
      Exit Do
    End If
    RowSrcTableLast = .Cells(RowSrcTableTitle,"A").End(xlDown).Row
  End With

  ' Process table RowSrcTableTitle to RowSrcTableLast

  RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcTableLast+1
Loop
```

Within the above loop we have: Process table RowSrcTableTitle to RowSrcTableLast.

Is the Name column always column "A"?  Is the Value column always the last column?  If not, you will have to search across the header row for the column names.

Is every table in the same sequence?  If not, you will have to sort them.  Does every table contain every row?  If not, your code for combining the tables will have to allow for this.

I hope the above gets you started.  Come back if you have specific questions.

**Second answer - Response to clarification**

I created a test worksheet *Jia Source* which looks like this:

[image: Example source worksheet]

You say that the tables are all the same size.  In this situation, the following code outputs to the Immediate Window the dimensions of each table.  The output from this code is:

```
Table A1:C6
Table A8:C13
Table A15:C20
```

For your tables you will need to change the values of constants TableHeight and TableWidth.  You will also have to change "Jia Source" to the name of your source worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractValue()

  Dim ColSrcLeft As Long
  Dim ColSrcRight As Long
  Dim RowSrcTitle As Long   ' First row or table
  Dim RowSrcHeader As Long  ' Header row of table
  Dim RowSrcEnd As Long     ' Last row of table

  Const TableHeight As Long = 4
  Const TableWidth As Long = 3

  RowSrcTitle = 1
  Do While True
    With Worksheets("Jia Source")
      If .Cells(RowSrcTitle, "A").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowSrcHeader = RowSrcTitle + 1
      RowSrcEnd = RowSrcHeader + TableHeight
      ColSrcLeft = 1
      ColSrcRight = ColSrcLeft + TableWidth - 1
      Debug.Print "Table " & colNumToCode(ColSrcLeft) & RowSrcTitle & ":" & _
                  colNumToCode(ColSrcRight) & RowSrcEnd
    End With

    ' Code to handle table goes here.

    RowSrcTitle = RowSrcEnd + 2

  Loop

End Sub
Function colNumToCode(ByVal colNum As Integer) As String

  ' Convert Excel column number to column identifier or code
  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.

  Dim code As String
  Dim partNum As Integer

  If colNum = 0 Then
    colNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    code = ""
    Do While colNum > 0
      partNum = (colNum - 1) Mod 26
      code = Chr(65 + partNum) & code
      colNum = (colNum - partNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
    colNumToCode = code
  End If

End Function
```

I have left the code that shows how to search for the tables if they vary in size.  If the above code does not produce the correct results for your worksheet, you may need to merge the two routines.

The following assumes RowSrcTitle, RowSrcHeader, RowSrcLast, ColSrcLeft and ColSrcRight are correct.  It is the code from ExtractValue() plus the code to copy the data to the destination sheet which I have named "Jia Destination".  Its output is:

[image: Example destination worksheet]

Have a play.  Come back with questions if necessary.

```
Sub ExtractValue2()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcLeft As Long
  Dim ColSrcRight As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim RowDestBottom As Long
  Dim RowDestTop As Long
  Dim RowSrcTitle As Long   ' First row or table
  Dim RowSrcHeader As Long  ' Header row of table
  Dim RowSrcEnd As Long     ' Last row of table
  Dim TableTitle As String
  Dim CellArray() As Variant

  Const TableHeight As Long = 4
  Const TableWidth As Long = 3

  RowSrcTitle = 1
  ColDestCrnt = 1
  RowDestTop = 1
  RowDestBottom = RowDestTop + TableHeight

  Do While True
    With Worksheets("Jia Source")
      If .Cells(RowSrcTitle, "A").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowSrcHeader = RowSrcTitle + 1
      RowSrcEnd = RowSrcHeader + TableHeight
      ColSrcLeft = 1
      ColSrcRight = ColSrcLeft + TableWidth - 1

    End With

    If ColDestCrnt = 1 Then
      ' Column 1, the list of names, has not been output.
      ' This assumes all tables have the same rows in the same
      ' sequence

      With Worksheets("Jia Source")
        ' This statement loads all the values in a range to an array in a
        ' single statements.  Ask if you want more detail on what I am doing.
        ' Load name column for this table
        CellArray = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcHeader, ColSrcLeft), _
                           .Cells(RowSrcEnd, ColSrcLeft)).Value
      End With
      With Worksheets("Jia Destination")
        ' Clear destination sheet
        .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
        ' Write array containing name column to destination sheet
        .Range(.Cells(RowDestTop, 1), _
                 .Cells(RowDestBottom, 1)).Value = CellArray
      End With
      ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
    End If

    With Worksheets("Jia Source")
      ' Find Value column.
      Found = False
      For ColSrcCrnt = ColSrcLeft + 1 To ColSrcRight
        If LCase(.Cells(RowSrcHeader, ColSrcCrnt).Value) = "value" Then
          Found = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    End With
    ' If Found is False, the table has no value column and is ignored
    If Found Then
      With Worksheets("Jia Source")
        ' Extract title of title
        TableTitle = .Cells(RowSrcTitle, ColSrcLeft).Value
        ' Load name column (excluding header) for this table
          CellArray = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcHeader + 1, ColSrcCrnt), _
                             .Cells(RowSrcEnd, ColSrcCrnt)).Value
      End With
      With Worksheets("Jia Destination")
        ' Copy title
        .Cells(1, ColDestCrnt).Value = TableTitle
        ' Write array containing name column to destination sheet
        .Range(.Cells(RowDestTop + 1, ColDestCrnt), _
               .Cells(RowDestBottom, ColDestCrnt)).Value = CellArray
      End With
      ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1
    End If

    RowSrcTitle = RowSrcEnd + 2

  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Tony! 1 Yes, the tables are of the same size, but not not 3x3. They have the same number of rows and columns.2 Yes, the Name column is always column A. The Value column is not the last column. That's why I feel difficult. Since I need to search each data block, then search for the value column. 3 what do you mean by "Is every table in the same sequence?" Every table contain the same row. i.e. the corresponding row in each table has the same meaning.

Comment: ColSrcLast = .Cells(RowCrnt,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  This may not work correctly. Since for my data, "block1", "block2" and etc do exist and take the first cell of each table.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ColSrcLast = .Cells(RowCrnt+1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`.  That is, I wanted the last column of row below the title.

Comment: Point 3.  I wanted to know if one table was a-b-c and another b-a-c.  You confirm they are all the same which is much easier.  I will add to my answer to response to your other points.

Comment: Thanks so much, Tony! I created a same excel, and your code works perfectly! However, I have a further requirement, that some tables may miss certain rows. I have modified my question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to new question**

If your final clarification is correct, this code is more complicated than you need.  Before you posted it I had created a routine capable of handling much more varied tables than you assume you need.  Since you have not seen the "real" files, I have not removed the code to handle the full, possible complexity.

I creates a test worksheet like this:

[image: Example test data]

I suggest you duplicate this worksheet since it contains every nasty problem I could think of.  Try out this code with this worksheet.  Try to understand what the code is doing and why.  You should then be ready for anything the real tables throw at you.

Some of the code is complex and I had to define a User-Defined Data Type.  I tried googling "vba User-Defined Data Type" and was very disappointed by the tutorials I found so I will have a go myself.

Suppose my macro needs to hold name and age for a number of people.  I will clearly need some arrays:

```
Dim NameFamily() As String
Dim NameGiven() As String
Dim Age() As Long

ReDim NameFamily(1 to 20)
ReDim NameGiven(1 to 3, 1 to 20)
ReDim Age(1 to 20)

NameFamily(5) = "Dallimore"
NameGiven(1, 5) = "Anthony"
NameGiven(2, 5) = "John"
NameGiven(3, 5) = ""
Age(5) = 65
```

You can very easily end up with a lot of code that can be difficult to maintain; particularly as the number of variables per person increases.

The alternative is to use what most languages call a structure and VBA calls a user-defined data type:

```
Type Person
  NameFamily As String
  NameGiven() As String
  NumGivenNames as Long
  Age As Long
 End Type
```

*Person* is a new data type and I can declare variables using this type:

```
Dim Boss As Person
Dim OtherStaff() As Person

ReDim OtherStaff(1 to 20)

OtherStaff(5).NameFamily = "Dallimore"
OtherStaff(5).NumGivenNames = 2
Redim OtherStaff(5).NameGiven(1 To OtherStaff(5).NumGivenNames) 
OtherStaff(5).NameGiven(1) = "Anthony"
OtherStaff(5).NameGiven(2) = "John"
OtherStaff(5).Age = 65
```

This probably does not look any easier.  The benefits become more obvious when you want to add another item of information about people; perhaps number of children.  With regular arrays, you first have to add a new array.  You then have to find every point within the code where you resize the person arrays and add a ReDim statement for the new array.  You get strange errors if you miss any ReDim.  With the user defined data types, you add one line to the Type definition:

```
Type Person
  NameFamily As String
  NameGiven() As String
  NumGivenNames as Long
  Age As Long
  NumChildren As Long 
 End Type
```

All existing code is now fully updated for this new variable.

The above is a very brief introduction but I believe it covers every feature of user-defined data types that I used in the code.

I hope I have included enough comments to allow you to understand my code.  Work through it slowly and ask questions if necessary.

*The code below is a third version having been updated to address questions on the earlier versions.*

*Variable naming conventions*

Names are of the form AaaaBbbbCccc where each name part reduces the scope of name.  So "Col" is short for column.  Any variable used as a column number starts "Col".  "Dest" is short for destination and "Src" is short for "Source".  So any variable starting "ColSrc" is a column number for the source worksheet.

If I have an array AaaaBbbbCccc, any indices for that array will start InxAaaaBbbbCccc unless the resulting name is too long in which case Aaaa, Bbbb and Cccc are abbreviated or discarded.  So all indices for "NameDtl()" start "InxName" because I think "InxNameDtl" is too long.

"Crnt" is short for "Current" and typically indicates a for-loop variable or a value extracted from an array for one iteration of a for-loop.

```
Option Explicit
Type typNameDtl
  InxPredCrntMax As Long
  Name As String
  Output As Boolean
  Predecessor() As String
End Type

Sub ExtractValue3()

  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long          ' Current column of destination worksheet
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long           ' Current column of source worksheet
  Dim ColSrcSheetLast As Long      ' Last column of worksheet
  Dim InxNISCrnt As Long           ' Current index into NameInSeq array
  Dim InxNISCrntMax As Long        ' Index of last used entry in NameInSeq array
  Dim InxNISFirstThisPass As Long  ' Index of first entry in NameInSeq array
                                   ' used this pass
  Dim InxNameCrnt As Long          ' Current index into NameDtl array
  Dim InxNameCrntMax As Long       ' Index of last used entry in NameDtl array
  Dim InxPredCrnt As Long          ' Current index into NameDtl(N).Predecessor
                                   ' array
  Dim InxPredCrntMaxCrnt As Long   ' Temporary copy of
                                   ' NameDtl(N).InxPredecessorCrntMax
  Dim InxTableCrnt As Long         ' Current index into RowSrcTableTitle and
                                   ' RowSrcTableEnd arrays
  Dim InxTableCrntMax As Long      ' Last used entry in RowSrcTableTitle and
                                   ' RowSrcTableEnd arrays
  Dim Found As Boolean             ' Set to True if a loop finds what is
                                   ' being sought
  Dim NameCrnt As String           ' Current index into NameDtl array
  Dim NameInSeq() As String        ' Array of names in output sequence
  Dim NameLenMax As Long           ' Maximum length of a name.  Only used to
                                   ' align columns in diagnostic output.
  Dim NameDtl() As typNameDtl      ' Array of names found and their predecessors
  Dim PredNameCrnt As String       ' Current predecessor name.  Used when
                                   ' searching NameDtl(N).Predecessor
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long          ' Current row of destination worksheet
  Dim RowSrcCrnt1 As Long          ' \ Indices into source worksheet allowing
  Dim RowSrcCrnt2 As Long          ' / nested searches
  Dim RowSrcTableEnd() As Long     ' Array holding last row of each table within
                                   ' source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcTableEndCrnt As Long   ' The last row of the current table
  Dim RowSrcSheetLast As Long      ' Last row of source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcTableTitle() As Long   ' Array holding title row of each table within
                                   ' source worksheet
  Dim RowSrcTableTitleCrnt As Long ' Title row of current table
  Dim SheetValue() As Variant      ' Copy of source worksheet.

  ' Column A of source worksheet used to test this code:

  '    Start
  '    row     Values in starting and following rows
  '      2      block1  name  c  d  e  f
  '      9      block2  name  b  c  d  e
  '     16      block3  name  a  c  d
  '     22      block4  name  a  d  e
  '     29      block5  name  a  d  f
  '     36      block6  name  d  e  f

  ' Note that a and b never appear together in a table; it is impossible
  ' to deduce their preferred sequence from this data.

  ' Stage 1: Load entire source worksheet into array.
  ' =================================================
  With Worksheets("Jia Source")
    ' Detrmine dimensions of worksheet
    RowSrcSheetLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , _
                                                       xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColSrcSheetLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , _
                                                 xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    SheetValue = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), _
                        .Cells(RowSrcSheetLast, ColSrcSheetLast)).Value
    ' SheetValue is a one-based array with rows as the first dimension and
    ' columns as the second.  An array loaded from a worksheet is always one-based
    ' even if the range does not start at Cells(1,1).  Because this range starts
    ' at Cells(1,1), indices into SheetValue match row and column numbers within
    ' the worksheet.  This match is convenient for diagnostic output but is not
    ' used by the macro which does not reference the worksheet, RowSrcSheetLast or
    ' ColSrcSheet again.
  End With

  ' Stage 2: Locate each table and store number of
  ' title row and last data row in arrays.
  ' ==============================================

  ' 100 entries may be enough.  The arrays are enlarged if necessary.
  ReDim RowSrcTableEnd(1 To 100)
  ReDim RowSrcTableTitle(1 To 100)
  InxTableCrntMax = 0           ' Arrays currently empty

  RowSrcCrnt1 = 1

  ' Loop identifying dimensions of tables
  Do While RowSrcCrnt1 <= RowSrcSheetLast

    ' Search down for the first row of a table
    Found = False
    Do While RowSrcCrnt1 <= RowSrcSheetLast
      If SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt1, 1) <> "" Then
        RowSrcTableTitleCrnt = RowSrcCrnt1
        Found = True
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowSrcCrnt1 = RowSrcCrnt1 + 1
    Loop
    If Not Found Then
      ' All tables located
      Exit Do
    End If

    ' Search down for the last row of a table
    Found = False
    Do While RowSrcCrnt1 <= RowSrcSheetLast
      If SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt1, 1) = "" Then
        RowSrcTableEndCrnt = RowSrcCrnt1 - 1
        Found = True
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowSrcCrnt1 = RowSrcCrnt1 + 1
    Loop
    If Not Found Then
      ' Last table extends down to bottom of worksheet
        RowSrcTableEndCrnt = RowSrcSheetLast
    End If

    ' Store details of this table.
    InxTableCrntMax = InxTableCrntMax + 1

    ' Enlarge arrays if they are full
    If InxTableCrntMax > UBound(RowSrcTableTitle) Then
      ' Redim Preserve requires the interpreter find a block of memory
      ' of the new size, copy values across from the old array and
      ' release the old array for garbage collection.  I always allocate
      ' extra memory in large chunks and use an index like
      ' InxTableCrntMax to record how much of the array has been used.
      ReDim Preserve RowSrcTableTitle(UBound(RowSrcTableTitle) + 100)
      ReDim Preserve RowSrcTableEnd(UBound(RowSrcTableTitle) + 100)
    End If

    RowSrcTableTitle(InxTableCrntMax) = RowSrcTableTitleCrnt
    RowSrcTableEnd(InxTableCrntMax) = RowSrcTableEndCrnt

  Loop

  ' Output the arrays to the Immediate window to demonstrate they are correct.
  ' For my test data, the output is:
  '   Elements:  1  2  3  4  5  6
  '      Title:  2  9 16 22 29 36
  '  Last data:  7 14 20 26 33 40

  Debug.Print "Location of each table"
  Debug.Print " Elements:";
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To InxTableCrntMax
    Debug.Print Right("   " & InxTableCrnt, 3);
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "    Title:";
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To InxTableCrntMax
    Debug.Print Right("   " & RowSrcTableTitle(InxTableCrnt), 3);
  Next
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "Last data:";
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To InxTableCrntMax
    Debug.Print Right("   " & RowSrcTableEnd(InxTableCrnt), 3);
  Next
  Debug.Print

  ' Stage 3.  Build arrays listing predecessors of each name
  ' ========================================================

  ' The names within the tables are all in the same sequence but no table
  ' contains more than a few names so that sequence is not obvious. This
  ' stage accumulates data from the tables so that Stage 4 can deduce the full
  ' sequence.  More correctly, Stage 4 deduces a sequence that does not
  ' contradict the tables because the sequence of a and b and the sequence
  ' of f and g is not defined by these tables.

  ' For Stage 4, I need a list of every name used in the tables and, for each
  ' name, a list of its predecessors.  Consider first the list of names.

  ' NameDtl is initialised to NameDtl(1 to 50) and InxNameCrntMax is initialised
  ' to 0 to record the array is empty.  In table 1, the code below finds c, d,
  ' e and f.  NameDtl and InxNameCrntMax are updated as these names are found:
  '
  '    Initial state: InxNameCrntMax = 0   NameDtl empty
  '    Name c found : InxNameCrntMax = 1   NameDtl(1).Name = "c"
  '    Name d found : InxNameCrntMax = 2   NameDtl(2).Name = "d"
  '    Name e found : InxNameCrntMax = 3   NameDtl(3).Name = "e"
  '    Name f found : InxNameCrntMax = 4   NameDtl(4).Name = "f"

  ' In table 2, the code finds; b, c, d  and e.  b is new but c, d and e are
  ' already recorded and they must not be added again.  For each name found,
  ' the code checks entries 1 to InxNameCrntMax.  Only if the new name is not
  ' found, is it added.

  ' For each name, Stage 4 needs to know its predecessors.  From table 1 it
  ' records that:
  '    d is preceeded by c
  '    e is preceeded by c and d
  '    f is preceeded by c, d and e

  ' The same technique is used for build the list of predecessors.  The
  ' differences are:
  '   1) Names are accumulated in NameDtl().Name while the predecessors of
  '      the fifth name are accumulated in NameDtl(5).Predecessor.
  '   2) InxNameCrntMax is replaced, for the fifth name, by
  '      NameDtl(5).InxPredCrntMax.

  ' Start with space for 50 names.  Enlarge if necessary.
  ReDim NameDtl(1 To 50)
  InxNameCrntMax = 0       ' Array is empty

  ' For each table
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To InxTableCrntMax

    RowSrcTableTitleCrnt = RowSrcTableTitle(InxTableCrnt)
    RowSrcTableEndCrnt = RowSrcTableEnd(InxTableCrnt)

    ' For each data row in the current table
    For RowSrcCrnt1 = RowSrcTableTitleCrnt + 2 To RowSrcTableEndCrnt

      ' Look in NameDtl for name from current data row
      NameCrnt = SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt1, 1)
      Found = False
      For InxNameCrnt = 1 To InxNameCrntMax
        ' Not this comparison is case sensitive "John" and "john" would not
        ' match.  Use LCase if case insensitive comparison required.
        If NameCrnt = NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name Then
          Found = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If Not Found Then
        ' This is a new name.  Create entry in NameDtl for it.
        InxNameCrntMax = InxNameCrntMax + 1
        If InxNameCrntMax > UBound(NameDtl) Then
          ReDim Preserve NameDtl(UBound(NameDtl) + 50)
        End If
        InxNameCrnt = InxNameCrntMax
        NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Output = False
        NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name = NameCrnt
        ' Allow for up to 20 predecessors
        ReDim NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(1 To 20)
        NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax = 0
      End If
      ' Check that each predecessor for the current name within the
      ' current table is recorded against the current name
      For RowSrcCrnt2 = RowSrcTableTitleCrnt + 2 To RowSrcCrnt1 - 1
        Found = False
        PredNameCrnt = SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt2, 1)
        ' Move current number of predecessors from array to variable
        ' to make code more compact and easier to read
        InxPredCrntMaxCrnt = NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax
        For InxPredCrnt = 1 To InxPredCrntMaxCrnt
          If PredNameCrnt = _
                  NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(InxPredCrnt) Then
            Found = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If Not Found Then
          ' This predecessor has not been recorded against the current name
          InxPredCrntMaxCrnt = InxPredCrntMaxCrnt + 1
          If InxPredCrntMaxCrnt > _
                         UBound(NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor) Then
            ReDim Preserve NameDtl(UBound(NameDtl) + 20)
          End If
          NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(InxPredCrntMaxCrnt) = PredNameCrnt
          ' Place new value for number of predecessors in its permenent store.
          NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax = InxPredCrntMaxCrnt
        End If
      Next
    Next
  Next

  ' Output NameDtl to the Immediate window to demonstrate it is correct.

  ' Find length of longest name so columns can be justified
  NameLenMax = 4         ' Minimum length is that of title
 For InxNameCrnt = 1 To InxNameCrntMax
    If Len(NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name) > NameLenMax Then
      NameLenMax = Len(NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name)
    End If
  Next
  ' Output headings
  Debug.Print vbLf & "Contents of NameDtl table"
  Debug.Print Space(NameLenMax + 10) & "Max"
  Debug.Print Left("Name" & Space(NameLenMax), NameLenMax + 2) & _
              "Output  inx  Predecessors"
  ' Output table contents
  For InxNameCrnt = 1 To InxNameCrntMax
    Debug.Print Left(NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name & Space(NameLenMax), _
                   NameLenMax + 4) & _
                   IIf(NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Output, " True ", " False") & _
                   "  " & Right("   " & _
                   NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax, 3) & " ";
    For InxPredCrnt = 1 To NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax
      Debug.Print "  " & _
                     NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(InxPredCrnt);
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

  ' Stage 4: Sequence names for list.
  ' =================================

  ' The output from the above routine for the test data is:

  '                Max
  '  Name  Output  inx  Predecessors
  '  c     False    2   b  a
  '  d     False    3   c  b  a
  '  e     False    4   c  d  b  a
  '  g     False    3   c  d  e
  '  b     False    0
  '  a     False    0
  '  f     False    3   a  d  e

  ' Note 1: All this information is in the sequence found.
  ' Note 2: We do not know the "true" sequence of b and a or of g and f.

  ' The loop below has three steps:
  '   1) Transfer any names to NamesInSeq() that have not already been
  '      transferred and have a value of 0 for Max inx.
  '   2) If no names are transferred, the loop has completed its task.
  '   3) Remove any names transferred during this pass from the predecessor
  '      lists and mark the name as output.

  ' Before the loop NameInSeq() is empty, InxNISCrntMax = 0 and
  ' InxNISFirstThisPass = InxNISCrntMax+1 = 1.

  ' After step 1 of pass 1:
  '     NameInSeq(1) = "b" and NameInSeq(2) = "a"
  '     InxNISCrntMax = 2
  ' Entries InxNISFirstThisPass (1) to InxNISCrntMax (2) of NamesInSeq have
  ' been transferred during this pass so names a and b are removed from the
  ' lists by copying the last entry in each list over the name to be removed
  ' and reducing Max inx.  For pass 1, only the list for f is changed.

  ' At the end of pass 1, NameDtl is:

  '                Max
  '  Name  Output  inx  Predecessors
  '  c     False    0
  '  d     False    1   c
  '  e     False    2   c  d
  '  g     False    3   c  d  e
  '  b      True    0
  '  a      True    0
  '  f     False    2   e  d

  ' During pass 2, c is moved to NamesInSeq and removed form the lists to give:

  '                Max
  '  Name  Output  inx  Predecessors
  '  c      True    0
  '  d     False    0
  '  e     False    1   d
  '  g     False    2   e  d
  '  b      True    0
  '  a      True    0
  '  f     False    2   e  d

  ' This process continues until all names have been transferred.

  ' Size array for total number of names.
  ReDim NameInSeq(1 To InxNameCrntMax)
  InxNISCrntMax = 0       ' Array empty

  ' Loop until every name has been moved
  ' from ProdecessorDtl to NameInSeq.
  Do While True
    Found = False   ' No name found to move during this pass
    '  Record index of first name, if any, to be added during this pass
    InxNISFirstThisPass = InxNISCrntMax + 1

    ' Transfer names without predecessors to NameInSeq()
    For InxNameCrnt = 1 To InxNameCrntMax
      If Not NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Output Then
        ' This name has not been output
        If NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax = 0 Then
          ' This name has no predecessors or no predecessors that
          ' have not already been transferred to NameInSeq()
          InxNISCrntMax = InxNISCrntMax + 1
          NameInSeq(InxNISCrntMax) = NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Name
          NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Output = True
          Found = True
        End If
      End If
    Next

    If Not Found Then
      ' All names already transferred to NameInSeq
      Exit Do
    End If

    ' Remove references to names transferred to NameinSeq()
    ' during this pass
    For InxNISCrnt = InxNISFirstThisPass To InxNISCrntMax
      NameCrnt = NameInSeq(InxNISCrnt)
      For InxNameCrnt = 1 To InxNameCrntMax
        If Not NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Output Then
          ' This name has not been output
          For InxPredCrnt = 1 To NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax
            If NameCrnt = _
               NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(InxPredCrnt) Then
              ' Remove this name by overwriting it
              ' with the last name in the list
              NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor(InxPredCrnt) = _
                      NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).Predecessor _
                               (NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax)
              NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax = _
                             NameDtl(InxNameCrnt).InxPredCrntMax - 1
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Next
    Next
  Loop

  Debug.Print vbLf & "Name list"
  For InxNISCrnt = 1 To InxNISCrntMax
    Debug.Print NameInSeq(InxNISCrnt)
  Next

  ' Stage 5: Transfer data
  ' ======================

  ' We now have everything we need for the transfer:
  '  * NameInSeq() contains the names in the output sequence
  '  * SheetValue() contains all the data from the source worksheet
  '  * RowSrcTableTitle() and RowSrcTableEnd() identify the
  '    start and end row of each table

  With Worksheets("Jia Destination")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete         ' Clear destination sheet

    ColDestCrnt = 1
    .Cells(1, ColDestCrnt).Value = "Name"
    ' Output names
    RowDestCrnt = 2
    For InxNISCrnt = 1 To InxNISCrntMax
      .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = NameInSeq(InxNISCrnt)
      RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
    Next

    ' Output values from each table
    For InxTableCrnt = 1 To InxTableCrntMax

      RowSrcTableTitleCrnt = RowSrcTableTitle(InxTableCrnt)
      RowSrcTableEndCrnt = RowSrcTableEnd(InxTableCrnt)

      ' Find value column, if any
      Found = False
      ColSrcCrnt = 2
      Do While SheetValue(RowSrcTableTitleCrnt + 1, ColSrcCrnt) <> ""
        If LCase(SheetValue(RowSrcTableTitleCrnt + 1, ColSrcCrnt)) = _
                                                                    "value" Then
          Found = True
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColSrcCrnt = ColSrcCrnt + 1
      Loop

      If Found Then
        ' Value column found for this table

        ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 1

        ' Transfer table name
        .Cells(1, ColDestCrnt).Value = SheetValue(RowSrcTableTitleCrnt, 1)

        ' Transfer values
        RowDestCrnt = 2
        RowSrcCrnt1 = RowSrcTableTitleCrnt + 2
        For InxNISCrnt = 1 To InxNISCrntMax
          If NameInSeq(InxNISCrnt) = SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt1, 1) Then
            ' Value for this name in this table
            .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
                                             SheetValue(RowSrcCrnt1, ColSrcCrnt)
            ' Value transferred from this row.  Step to next if any
            RowSrcCrnt1 = RowSrcCrnt1 + 1
            If RowSrcCrnt1 > RowSrcTableEndCrnt Then
              ' No more rows in this table
              Exit For
            End If
          End If
          RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
        Next
      Else
        Call MsgBox("Table starting at row " & RowSrcTableTitleCrnt & _
                    " does not have a value column", vbOKOnly)
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear about the code block of "Check that each predecessor for the current name within the current table is recorded against the current name". I think it's like constructing the PredecessorDtl array, i.e. fill in the array with each row name and its corresponding predecessors, right? If so, what does the last line in this block mean ? `PredecessorDtl(InxPredDtlCrnt).Predecessor(PredecessorDtl(InxPredDtlCrnt).InxPredCrntMax) = PredNameCrnt`

Comment: 2. Could you explain the meaning of the code block under "Remove references to names transferred to NameinSeq()on this pass"?

Comment: Over the last 20 hours I have updated my answer three or four times. I have renamed PredecessorDtl as NameDtl which I think makes the code clearer and I have added explanations which together answer, I believe, all your questions. I have deleted comments which are now within the answer. Please delete questions which are answered to your satisfaction so I know if any are still outstanding.

Comment: I believe your comparison with constructing a HashMap in Java misses the point. I have used this technique, more-or-less unchanged, in many different languages because I do not know a better technique for building up such as list.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! I've deleted some comments and am working on it. Will delete them till I fully understand.